# How to merge two single column csv files with linux commands

Tags: linux, csv

I was wondering how to merge two single column csv files into one file where the resulting file will contain two columns.

file1.csv
   first_name
   chris
   ben
   jerry

file2.csv
   last_name
   smith
   white
   perry

result.csv
   first_name,last_name
   chris,smith
   ben,white
   jerry,perry

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
$ cat file1
John
Mary
$ cat file2
Smith
Jones
$ paste -d, file1 file2
John,Smith
Mary,Jones
```

The `-d,` argument is used to designate commas as the delimiter between columns

Answer (score 8):

You're looking for [`paste`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/paste).