# How do I combine 2 csv files + all content + cygwin/bash/awk/sed/paste

Tags: bash, csv, awk, sed, merge

How do I combine 2 CSV files(finle1.csv and file2.csv)? I have explored awk/sed/paste but it is beyond me.

file1.csv

```
Time,Object,Integrity,KPI 1-A Name A unit(unit/s),KPI 2-A Name B unit(unit/s)
2014-06-04 11:00,ObjectA,100%,0.0316,0.0012
2014-06-04 21:00,ObjectB,100%,40.0332,7.2601
```

file2.csv

```
Time,Object,Integrity,KPI 1-C Name A unit(unit),KPI 1-D Name A unit(unit)
2014-06-04,ObjectA,100%,0.024,0.0014
2014-06-04,ObjectB,100%,60.6176,29.0913
```

whatIwant.csv

```
Time,Object,Integrity,KPI 1-A Name A unit(unit/s),KPI 2-A Name B unit(unit/s),Time,Object,Integrity,KPI 1-C Name A unit(unit),KPI 1-D Name A unit(unit)
2014-06-04 11:00,ObjectA,100%,0.0316,0.0012,2014-06-04,ObjectA,100%,0.024,0.0014
2014-06-04 21:00,ObjectB,100%,40.0332,7.2601,2014-06-04,ObjectB,100%,60.6176,29.0913
```

Note: I am assuming Time, Object will line up accordingly.

This will be for N rows.

Also the number of columns will possibly increase in each file.

I may have to remove the 2nd Time,Object,Integrity columns from the `whatIwant.csv` but can do this later.

Comment: I'd suggest having a look here http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ad_Hoc_Data_Analysis_From_The_Unix_Command_Line it is a crash course in what you need to do

Comment: tks, found this [way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10117767/how-to-merge-two-single-column-csv-files-with-linux-commands) also

Comment: You can also use `join` instead of `paste` to remove the repeated fields. Either that or parsing the output to remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$2]=$0;next}$2 in a{ print a[$2],$4, $5 }' OFS=, file1.csv file2.csv
Time,Object,Integrity,KPI 1-A Name A unit(unit/s),KPI 2-A Name B unit(unit/s),KPI 1-C Name A unit(unit),KPI 1-D Name A unit(unit)
2014-06-04 11:00,ObjectA,100%,0.0316,0.0012,0.024,0.0014
2014-06-04 21:00,ObjectB,100%,40.0332,7.2601,60.6176,29.0913
```

Using `join`:

```
join -t, -j 2 -o 1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4 1.5 2.4 2.5 file1.csv file2.csv
Time,Object,Integrity,KPI 1-A Name A unit(unit/s),KPI 2-A Name B unit(unit/s),KPI 1-C Name A unit(unit),KPI 1-D Name A unit(unit)
2014-06-04 11:00,ObjectA,100%,0.0316,0.0012,0.024,0.0014
2014-06-04 21:00,ObjectB,100%,40.0332,7.2601,60.6176,29.0913
```

**Update:**

To join on date and object, you can use `awk` as `join` only joins on 1 column.

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR{sub(/ .*/,"",$1);map[$1,$2]=$0;next}(($1,$2) in map){print map[$1,$2],$4,$5}' OFS=, f1 f2
Time,Object,Integrity,KPI 1-A Name A unit(unit/s),KPI 2-A Name B unit(unit/s),KPI 1-C Name A unit(unit),KPI 1-D Name A unit(unit)
2014-06-04,ObjectA,100%,0.0316,0.0012,0.024,0.0014
2014-06-04,ObjectB,100%,40.0332,7.2601,60.6176,29.0913
```

Comment: many thanks for this but can you give a brief explanation of this? as I would like to apply it to similar data that looks more like this with all values between double-quotes `"Time","Object","Integrity","KPI 1-A Name A unit(unit/s)","KPI 2-A Name B unit(unit/s)"`

Comment: @HattrickNZ For quoted CSV I won't recommend awk at all. Use something that comes with a proper CSV parser like perl or ruby.