# Explain awk command about merging csv files

Tags: csv, awk

I found a useful [awk command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24050276/471461) from a person who had the same [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24049223/471461) as me.

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$2]=$0;next}$2 in a{ print a[$2],$4, $5 }' OFS=, file1.csv file2.csv
```

I'm trying to modify it to suit our csv format, but I'm having a hard time to understand what it does. I sadly had to do this in a short time notice, and I hope you guys can help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
-F,
```

Set `FS` to `,` for field splitting.

```
NR==FNR{a[$2]=$0;next}
```

When the current processed line number (`NR`) is equal to the current file's line number (`FNR`) (i.e. when processing the first non-empty file). Store input lines into the `a` array under a key of the second field of the line (`$2`) and skip to processing the next line (`next`).

```
$2 in a{ print a[$2],$4, $5 }
```

When the second field of the current line (`$2`) is in the array `a` print the field from the array under this key `a[$2]` followed by `OFS` (the comma) followed by field four of the current line (`$4`) followed by `OFS` followed by field five of the current line (`$5`).

```
OFS=,
```

Set `OFS` to `,` before processing the input files.

tl;dr Append columns four and five from `file2.csv` to matching lines (based on field two) from `file1.csv`.

Answer (score 3):

```
-F,          # Set the field separator to a comma

NR==FNR      # Test if we are looking the first file
             # NR is incremented for every line read across all input files
             # FNR is incremented for every line read in current file and resets to 0
             # The only time NR==FNR is when we are looking at the first file

a[$2]=$0     # Create a lookup for the line based on the value in the 2nd column

next         # Short circuit the script and get the next input line

$2 in a      # If we are here we are looking at the second file 
             # Check if we have seen the second field in the first file

a[$2],$4,$5  # Print the whole matching line from the first file
             # with the 4th & 5th fields from the second

OFS=,        # Separate the output with a comma
```

Comment: wrt `The only time NR==FNR is when we are looking at the first file` or if we're looking at the 2nd file and the first file was empty. Something that trips people up occasionally so good to keep in mind.

Comment: @EdMorton better to use `ARGIND==1` and lose two characters

Comment: @Jidder That's GNU specific but yes it is a good solution for gawk. You could add `FNR==1{ARGIND++}` for non-gawks but that's back to failing on empty files. You could also use `FILENAME==ARGV[1]` but that fails if you're setting variables in the file names area (one more reason not to do that!). There's really no ideal solution so `NR==FNR` is usually fine, just need to bear in mind it'll fail if your first file is empty.

Comment: @EdMorton What do you mean setting variables in the file names area?

Comment: @Jidder: `awk '...' OFS=, file` vs `awk -v OFS=, '...' file`.

Comment: @Jidder Yeah, it only has one real use and that's when you need to change the initial value of a variable between file names, e.g. if file1 uses comma as a field separator, and file2 uses tab: `awk '...' FS=, file1 FS='\t' file2`

Comment: @EdMorton, I find NR==FNR very unintuitive. Do AWK programmers use it often or is it a common shorthand for a more explicit lines of code?

Comment: It is IMHO THE most common awk idiom. See the comments above between myself and @Jidder for the alterantives. The most robust way is to use GNU awk and `ARGIND==1`, etc. but then it's not portable to other awks. Every other approach, `NR==FNR` included, has caveats (one of which I didn't mention above is that `FILENAME==ARGV[1]` also fails if you're parsing the same file twice). If you want something fully robust, you need to write code in the BEGIN section to loop on ARGV[] and use `getline` to try to open each arg to see if its a readable file and then populate an array, etc. - not worth it.