# Find string from a file to another file in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, grep

I am new to shell scripting. Just wanna know how can I obtain the result I wanted with the following:

I have two files (FILE_A and FILE_B)

**FILE_A contains:**

```
   09228606355,71295939,1,http://sun.net.ph/043xafj.xml,01000001C123000D30
   09228505450,71295857,1,http://sun.net.ph/004xafk.xml,01000001C123000D30
```

**FILE_B contains:**

```
  http://sun.net.ph/161ybfq.xml                     ,9220002354016,93111
  http://sun.net.ph/004xafk.xml                     ,9220002354074,93111
```

If the URL (4th field) in FILE_A is present in FILE_B, the out will be:

```
  09228505450,71295857,1,http://sun.net.ph/004xafk.xml,01000001C123000D30,9220002354074,93111
```

It will display the whole line in FILE_A and added 2nd and 3rd field of FILE_B.

I hope my question is clear. Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how do I combine 2 csv files + all content + cygwin/bash/awk/sed/paste](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24049223/how-do-i-combine-2-csv-files-all-content-cygwin-bash-awk-sed-paste)

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/^\s*(\S+)\s*,(.*)/\\#^([^,]*,){3}\1#s#$#,\2#p/' fileB | sed -nrf - fileA
```

This builds a sed script from fileB and runs it against fileA. The second sed script is run in `silent` mode and only those lines that match the sed script are printed out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
paste -d , A B  | awk -F , '{if ($4==$6) print "match", $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$7,$8;}'
```

I removed the spaces in your file B for the `$4==$6` to work.

I use paste to create a composite line using `,` as the delimiter to get a line with , . I then use `awk` comparison to check the URLs from both files and if a match is found I print all the fields you care about.